# wordpress convert webconfig file to htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, web-config

I am trying to convert this web.config file to a .htaccess but cannot seem to get it correct. Can someone help?

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
  <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true"><match url=".*"/><conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"><add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/><add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/></conditions><action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/></rule>
        <rule name="WordPress: http://valiantstag.thetribestaging.com" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far, how does your current .htaccess look like?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the default htaccess/web.config. I you go to options > permalinks, then change the structure, it should force update the .htaccess file whenever the site is running on apache.

When .htaccess doesn't have write permissions, wordpress will ask you to manually update it's contents.